# Como usar uma variável JavaScript em uma pagina php via ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Basicamente eu preciso usar uma variavel JavaScript em uma php para depois registrar, no banco. Tenho um botao `<a href="carrinho.php"><button id="btnTestar">TESTE</button></a>` que leva ate a pagina carrinho.php.

Na pagina carrinho.php eu quero receber a variavel.

```
$teste = $_POST['teste'];
```

codigo ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnTestar").click(function(){
    var teste = "testando";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "carrinho.php",
          data:{'teste':teste},
          success: success,
          dataType: dataType
        });

    });
});
```

Eu não sei oque está errado pois nunca usei ajax antes então estou na duvida.
o erro que aparece na pagina php é essse`Notice: Undefined index: teste`

Comment: Tenta passar `teste: teste` ao invés de `'teste': teste`

Comment: Tente modificar no AJAX: data: teste

Answer (score 1):

Ao meu ver não faz sentido você redirecionar para mesma página que está enviando os dados via `ajax`.

Se fosse assim basta fazer um formulário básico com o seguinte código:

```
<form action="carrinho.php" method="post">
  <input name="teste" type="text" value="testando">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

A vantagem de utilizar o `ajax` é não precisar carregar a página novamente ou não ser direcionado para uma outra página.

O que nós podemos fazer é trazer os dados da outra página com o `ajax`.

Neste código abaixo é possível enviar a variável `teste` e receber o retorno pelo `ajax`, esse retorno será inserido na `div` com o id `result`.

No código PHP será lançada uma exceção caso o valor seja em branco.

Nesse código você pode apagar o valor do `input` para testar qualquer outro valor.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnTestar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'carrinho.php',   
      data: {
        teste: $('#teste').val()
      },
      success: function (result) {
        $('#result').html(result);
      },
      error: function (result) {
        $('#result').html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="teste" type="text" value="testando">
<button id="btnTestar">Teste</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

PHP:

```
$teste = $_POST['teste'];
if ($teste == '') {
    throw new Exception('Recebido valor em branco!');
} else {
    echo "Valor recebido: " . $teste;
}
```